# how to put this code in the button action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Can anyone faced a similar problem?
Maybe I missed what the appropriate action? First try to run this code in **AppDelegate** now at **ViewController** and have the same ..

**Or maybe someone knows how to put this code in the button action?**

maybe someone know, how to use UIPresentationPopoverController for presenting this ActionsViewController?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewDidAppear:animated];
        ActionsViewController *actionsViewController = [AppLibrary createActionsViewController];
        actionsViewController.actionDelegate = self;
        actionsViewController.supportedActionTypes = @[[[SupportedAction alloc] initWithActionType:ActionTypeEdit mediaTypes:@[kTypePNG]]];

        [actionsViewController setWhitelistedSubTypes:@[@"adjust", @"filter", @"healing"]];

        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            self.actionsNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:actionsViewController];
            [self presentViewController:self.actionsNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
}
```

Comment: Warning: Attempt to present <UINavigationController: > on <ViewController: > whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: Please edit the code to be more readable

Comment: 'who' is `self.actionsNavigationController` ?

Comment: Also, what class does `ActionsViewController` inherit from – is it a straight `UIViewController` subclass?

Comment: "He" is  the Action Registry view controller depending on  device/use case

Comment: Is there anything more to the error message, e.g. "…whose view is not in the window hierarchy"?

Comment: This view controller is designed to be displayed  modally on iPhone

Comment: When I compile the code, you receive only this error. I tried to put this code in the action button , but it did not work out((

Comment: you are trying to present a view-controller in viewdidappear. try to run that part of code with some delay. put your code in this block. // Delay 2 seconds
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        // your code
}

Comment: Or maybe someone knows how to put this code in the button action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it!:) it's work with UIPopoverPresentationController and button action

```
- (IBAction)popUp:(id)sender {

 ActionsViewController *actionsViewController = [AppLibrary createActionsViewController];
actionsViewController.actionDelegate = self;

actionsViewController.supportedActionTypes = @[[[SupportedAction alloc] initWithActionType:ActionTypeEdit mediaTypes:@[kTypePNG]]];

    [actionsViewController setWhitelistedSubTypes:@[@"adjust", @"filter", @"healing"]];

// present the controller
if(actionsViewController == nil) {
     actionsViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"popover"];
}
// present the controller

actionsViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 100);
actionsViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCustom;

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissMe)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];

 // configure the Popover presentation controller

UIPopoverPresentationController *popoverController = actionsViewController.popoverPresentationController;
popoverController.permittedArrowDirections  = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;
popoverController.delegate = self;
popoverController.sourceView = self.view;
popoverController.sourceRect =[sender frame];

 [self presentViewController:actionsViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)dismissMe {

NSLog(@"Popover was dismissed with internal tap");
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}



-(UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller {
return UIModalPresentationNone;   }
```

Answer (score 0):

--Workaround--
Just change this line:

`[self presentViewController:self.actionsNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];`

with this

```
UIViewController *rootVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
[rootVC presentViewController:self.actionsNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I has launched, but got black screen on my device and this error:                        Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController:

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to present a view-controller in viewdidappear.

Try to run that part of code with some delay. put your code in this block.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// your code

NewViewController *objNewviewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objNewviewController];

navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
});
```

And if you want to do this on button click then use this

```
-(IBAction)buttonclick:(id)sender
{
    NewViewController *objNewviewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewViewController"];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:objNewviewController];

    navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I checked the code and its working fine in both way. if it is not working for you then check that your viewcontroller is nil or not ? same for your navigationcontroller.

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: then put breakpoints in your code. and you will find that your viewcontroller or navigationcontroller may be NIL. it is not allocating properly.

Comment: I understande, that this cod is ok and should work; but it's not a  NewViewController, it is controller from SDK - built -in controller; and i'm shore its not nil

Comment: ok then try to replace my newcontroller with your controller from SDK. and assign to uinavigationcontroller. see if that works or not.

Comment: maybe you know, how to use UIPresentationPopoverController for
 presenting this ActionsViewController?